# Date value out of range (pandas)

Tags: python, pandas

I want to read an excel file using **pandas** **read_excel** method.

But it shows an out of range error for the date value . 
How can I fix this?.

```
df = pd.read_excel('/home/destiny2/Documents/elejio_data/Raipur/4 Star Hotels.xls')
```

error

```
return epoch + datetime.timedelta(days, seconds, 0, milliseconds)

OverflowError: date value out of range
```

Comment: Can You show some of the data int the excel sheet?

Comment: http://demo.xrosters.com/motorcycle_repaire.xlsx

Comment: @shivaManhar would you put your entire code? what is epoch?

Comment: I couldn't reproduce reported issue when parsing "motorcycle_repaire.xlsx"...